# "type -t commandName" not works in zsh, but works in bash

Tags: bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh

error log:
type: bad option: -t

why would zsh not use the same "type" of bash?
how can I achieve same function of "type -t commandName" of bash in zsh?
I can neither found the <type>'s manual or help in Zsh.

Comment: `type` is a builtin in `bash` and `zsh` and not the same executable. See [bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-type) compared to [zsh documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-type)

Comment: zsh and bash are two very different shells. They never were compatible with each other in the first place; for that matter, the thing that makes zsh distinct is its authors' willingness to outright break the POSIX specification when they disagree with it. (Not that this relates to `type` in particular but it speaks to the general willingness to be incompatible with everyone else when they think everyone else is wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zsh rough equivalent is `whence -w commandName` though the output is slightly different. This is a common problem for non-standard features where each shell has a slightly different solution to the same problem.

The documentation for the Zsh builtins is [`man zshbuiltins`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37839/zshbuiltins-1.html); the very top of `man zsh` displays a listing of the related manual pages.